# Как повысить производительность кафки и понять, почему консьюмер показывает низкую производительность?

Tags: jmeter, apache-kafka

Ситуация такая:
Есть кластер из 3 брокеров, есть генераторы нагрузки. Через jmeter отправляю продюсером простейшее сообщение, размером 350 байт, и пропускная способность составляет приблизительно 12 тысяч сообщений в секунду. Но консьюмер читает очень слабо, в районе 300-400 сообщений в секунду. Сейчас остановился на 6 партициях, и фактор репликации на 3. Консьюмер читает из всех партиций. При создании 6 консьюмеров производительность режется в полтора раза.Выкрутил все возможные надстройки в кафке, типа `queued.max.requests=500`, `num.network.threads`,
`num.io.threads`, пробовал с генератора увеличить число tcp соединений, замерял пропускную способность сети, нигде узких мест не увидел.

Программная часть и системные ресурсы тоже в пределах разумного утилизируются.